# why i cant get the result of pascal tri in the dom

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, dom

im trying to do the tri pascal exercice by onclick event but the result still undefined 
it seem like i dont know how i can call a function.

```js
        var call = function() {
            var numberOfRows = document.getElementById('Niveaux').value;;
            document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = generate(numberOfRows);
            document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = 'Triangle de pascal a '+numberOfRows+' Niveau';
        };

        var generate = function (numberOfRows) {
            //numberOfRows = document.getElementById('Niveau').value
            let triangle = [[1], [1,1]]
            if (numberOfRows === 0){
                return []
            }else if(numberOfRows == 1){
                return [[1]]
            }else if (numberOfRows == 2){
                return [[1], [1,1]]
            }else {
                for (var i = 2; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
                    addRow(triangle)
                }

            }

        };

        var addRow = function (triangle) {
            let previous = triangle[triangle.length - 1]
            let newRow = [1]
            for (var i = 0; i < previous.length - 1; i++) {
                let current = previous[i]
                let next = previous[i+1]
                newRow.push(current + next)
            }
            newRow.push(1)
            return triangle.push(newRow)
        }
```

```html
  <p>Niveau tri de pascal : <input type="text" id="Niveaux" value="10"></p>
    <button onclick="call()">Calcules</button><hr>
    <h3 id="result1"></h3>
    <p id="result2"></p>
```

Comment: sorry, i was angry
the problem in the undefined i dont understand exactly from  where the problem
im trying to display  a pascal triangle based on the number in the input it seem like i could'nt call the function generate and inner the result

Comment: Uncomment the first line in `generate`, and parse the value to number. All you get from the HTML is string, and the strict comparison doesn't pass when you're comparing a string against a number.

Answer (score 0):

> why i cant get the result of pascal tri in the dom?

Because when the `numberOfRows` entered by user's are greater than 2 i:e 3, 4, 5 etc, `else` part gets executed

```
else {
   for (var i = 2; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
      addRow(triangle);
   }

}
```

The returned value from function `addRow` is unused. Instead save the result of function in a variable and then return it.

Note - `triangle.push(newRow);` -> push function returns the new length of array.

```js
function call() {
  var numberOfRows = document.getElementById('Niveaux').value;;
  document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = generate(numberOfRows);
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = 'Triangle de pascal a ' + numberOfRows + ' Niveau';
};

var generate = function(numberOfRows) {
  numberOfRows = +(document.getElementById('Niveaux').value);
  let triangle = [
    [1],
    [1, 1]
  ]
  if (numberOfRows === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (numberOfRows == 1) {
    return [
      [1]
    ];
  } else if (numberOfRows == 2) {
    return [
      [1],
      [1, 1]
    ]
  } else {
    for (var i = 2; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
      result = addRow(triangle);
      return result;
    }
  }
  return numberOfRows;
};

var addRow = function(triangle) {
  let previous = triangle[triangle.length - 1];
  let newRow = [1];
  for (var i = 0; i < previous.length - 1; i++) {
    let current = previous[i];
    let next = previous[i + 1];
    newRow.push(current + next);
  }
  newRow.push(1);
  triangle.push(newRow);
  return triangle;
}
```

```html
<p>Niveau tri de pascal : <input type="text" id="Niveaux" value="10"></p>
<button onclick="call()">Calcules</button>
<hr>
<h3 id="result1"></h3>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

--Edit--

```js
function call() {
  var numberOfRows = document.getElementById('Niveaux').value;;
  generate(numberOfRows);
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = 'Triangle de pascal a ' + numberOfRows + ' Niveau';
};

var generate = function(numberOfRows) {
  numberOfRows = +(document.getElementById('Niveaux').value);
  let triangle = [
    [1],
    [1, 1]
  ]
  if (numberOfRows === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (numberOfRows == 1) {
    return [
      [1]
    ];
  } else if (numberOfRows == 2) {
    return [
      [1],
      [1, 1]
    ]
  } else {
    for (var i = 2; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
      addRow(triangle);
    }
  }
  printRow(triangle);
};

var addRow = function(triangle) {
  let previous = triangle[triangle.length - 1];
  let newRow = [1];
  for (var i = 0; i < previous.length - 1; i++) {
    let current = previous[i];
    let next = previous[i + 1];
    newRow.push(current + next);
  }
  newRow.push(1);
  triangle.push(newRow);
  return triangle;
}

const printRow = function(rows) {
  let pascalRow = "";
  for (let row of rows) {
    pascalRow += `${row.join(' ')} <br>`;
  }
  document.body.querySelector('#result2').innerHTML = pascalRow;
}
```

```html
<p>Niveau tri de pascal : <input type="text" id="Niveaux" value="10"></p>
<button onclick="call()">Calcules</button>
<hr>
<h3 id="result1"></h3>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

Comment: Not yet convinced brother more detail plz

Comment: @AbdelhakBoumezrag - Could you please clarify?

Comment: @AbdelhakBoumezrag -  See edit. You are already generating the array of rows, just need to display in DOM.